# How to secure Aes key in client side

Tags: aes

I have an app built on java, and a server built on vb.net

I'm using https to communicate between server and client

I also encrypt my post data using AES encryption

My question is how can secure my key and iv used in AES , so if someone decompile the apk he wont be able to decrypt and encrypt the data

Anyone who knows please provid an example, especially for client side

Comment: You can look into how browsers set up https connection. Short version is that you have a certificate which you use to exchange short lived AES keys. Are you sure the java library you use don't encrypt post data for you already?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://truelicense.net/xref/net/truelicense/obfuscate/ObfuscatedString.html

It can hide your key from being shown as plain text when the apk file is decompiled.

But using it just adds more security layer to your app, some guys with strong reverse engineer knowledge still can figure out how to de-obsfucate your key.